# How to use Serde to (de)serialize a tuple struct from JSON named values instead of an array?

Tags: json, serialization, rust, serde

I have a JSON object:

```
{ "min": 2, "max": 15 }
```

I'd like to parse it to this tuple struct:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct TeamSize(pub i64, pub i64);
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Match {
    size: TeamSize,
}
```

The current Serde serialization mechanism does not seem to provide the functionality of (de)serializing a tuple structure from named values instead of an array.

The generated (de)serialization mechanism expects the following:

```
{"size": [2, 15]}
```

I've tried to use Serde attributes, but I can't find one that does what I want:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct TeamSize(
    #[serde(rename = "min")]
    pub i64,
    #[serde(rename = "max")]
    pub i64
);
```

How to parse it? Should I implement everything by myself?

I've opened an [issue on the Serde repository](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/751).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct TeamSize(
    #[serde(rename = "min")]
    pub i64,
    #[serde(rename = "max")]
    pub i64
);
```

is not valid code, the Serde `rename` attribute only renames what is being serialized and deserialized, it does not change your code. In a tuple struct (your first one), you can (and must) omit names because you simply access them via self.0 and self.1, but a struct doesn't have a `first` or a `second` field, so you must add a name to them.

Like so:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct TeamSize {
    pub max: i64,
    pub min: i64,
};
```

Since the name of your attribute is the name of the JSON property (both `min` and `max`), you do not need to use `serde(rename)`. You would have needed it if your Rust struct used the fields `value_max` and `value_min` but your JSON still used `max` and `min`.

If you absolutely want to parse it to a tuple struct, you must implement `Serialize` and `Deserialize` for your custom struct yourself. I don't think it's worth the hassle though, just switch to a struct instead of a tuple struct.